# One or more users per database instance?

Tags: sql-server, instance

This is a very basic/fundamental question, so basic perhaps, that I can't find the answer.

In SQL Server 2012, one can make several instances of the database on the host server. But can several users use the same instance, or is a instance assigned to a specific user?

Put another way: would one make a "marketing" instance, such that all people from marketing would share that instance? (same log-on)

Or, is it one instance pr. user?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

One instance per user sounds ridiculously inefficient to me.  No one can share common data, and you have to create/delete an instance every time you add/remove a user.

If you use that design, how do you deal with archiving everyone's data?

I would go with a single instance, multiple users.  I'd have authentication/authorization in place to ensure that people only saw the data they were entitled to.

Comment: Thx :) How would the log-on procedure be? Continuing with the marketing instance: can they use their windows log on and be assigned to the correct instance. Or should they use sql authorization logon?

Comment: Your clients won't log onto the database directly.  That's 80s style client/server.  You'll want a middle tier between the client and the database to handle things like authentication, authorization, validation, page flow, and intercede on the client's behalf with the database.  That's a more service-oriented architecture.

Comment: That helped a lot. I will mainly be using SSAS and SSRS, but it is nice to have a grasp on the fundamentals as well :)

Answer (score 2):

A physical (or virtual) server 'machine' can have many instances of SQL Server.

Each instance of SQL Server can have many databases.

Each database can be used simultaneously by many (really many) users.

**Edit**

Re - your marketing department scenario

As duffymo states, although a SQL server instance does allow you to directly add Active Directory users (logins) and assign them privileges to one or more databases (as users), assigning roles and permissions on the way, this would typically only be for 2 or 2.5 tier software architectures (i.e. User runs an app on his / her desktop, each desktop connects to the SQL database). Nowadays, the app would be centralized (e.g. Web, or SOA), and only the app server(s) would connect to the database, handling the user security / access control concerns.

Comment: Thx :) Seems I have to update my drawing of SQL server, instances and related services. :D

Answer (score 1):

An "instance" is a fully independent install of the SQL engine on a server. Each instance can support multiple databases and each database can have many users simultaneously connected.

Comment: That was also a good reply. The database engine should then not be thought of as being assigned/connected to a specific DB (as it was in my head).